# Setting value of variable in HTML element with JQUERY not working

Tags: html, jquery

I have a div in my HTML like this in which I'd like to set the ID of capital using JQuery

```
`        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="capital"></p>
        </div>   `
```

This is how I'm setting it in my JQuery function

```
`function getWeather() {    
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/geojson/countryBorders.geo.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            
        },
        success: function(result) {
            let features = result["features"];

            let countryFeature = findFeatureFromName(countryName);
            let countryCode = JSON.stringify(countryFeature.properties.iso_a2).replace(/"/g,"")
    
            $.ajax({
            url: "assets/php/countryInformation.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                country: countryCode
            },
            success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    
                    let capitalCity = (result['data'][0]['capital']);
                    console.log(capitalCity)
                    $('#capital').html(capitalCity);`

etc
```

But capital isn't getting set?
The `console.log` is returning the expected value, so I know that has set okay.

I've even tried

```
$('#capital').text(capitalCity);
```

and plain JavaScript out of curiousity

```
document.getElementById("capital").innerHTML = capitalCity;
```

Nothing seems to be working and no errors in the console - what would be wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you open the developer tools console and type in $('#capital')? Do you get the element you are targeting? Have you checked that the element with the id of capital is unique?

Comment: @RobAnthony I get this ```$('#capital')
jQuery.fn.init [span#capital.info]
0
: 
span#capital.info
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object(0)```

Comment: @RobAnthony I've tried changing the id to ensure its entirely unique and even with that it's still not displaying

Comment: This suggests you have a span tag with the id of 'capital' as that is what it is finding, but the element you want to find is a <p> tag. View the source code and search for 'capital'

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and JSON code is correct Code it correct, may be you are missing something in your jSON file
Here is what I tried and got the Output, if possible please post
`ountryBorders.geo.json`, so that we get more clarity

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getWeather()">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p id="capital"></p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function getWeather() {
      debugger;
      let capitalCity = 'hello';
      console.log(capitalCity)
      $('#capital').html(capitalCity);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```